# Disable a part of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I want to disable `drop: handleCardDrop` from this part of the code.   *Hello guys*

```
for ( var i=1; i<=2; i++ ) {
 $('<div> </div>').appendTo( '#cardSlotsJoueur' ).droppable( { // droppable : the slot can receive a draggable card
 hoverClass: 'hovered', //css
 drop: handleCardDrop
 } );
}
```

Here is my html code:
http://pastebin.com/JtgUqcmA
Here is my js code:
http://pastebin.com/TLRsN0Vr

I tried to do it from a button html.

```
<input name="BoutonJoueur" type="submit" value="Joueur" onclick="javascript:CartesJoueur() ; drop.disable=true ; this.disabled = true" value="Save" style="width : 180px; height : 30px" ></td>
```

But it doesn't work.

In fact this is a poker game that works in one hand with drag and drop (it works nicely) and in the other hand with 4 button. The issue is that when i click on the "Joueur" button, i add an image in the backgound of the slot (where you drop your card). But you can still drag and drop an other card into it. That's wy i want to disable this when you click on the button ;-).

Could you help me?

*Thank you*

Comment: `handleCardDrop = undefined`?

Comment: I edited my question so that you can see the function handleCardDrop.

Comment: What is this a homework assignment? Same question was asked an hour ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755560/to-turn-off-droppable-with-html-onclick. What does `disable drop` mean? Why make it droppable in the first place

Comment: This is my workmate, we both work on the same project (poker game). As his question was unanswered, i judged necessary to write it in a way more understandable.

Comment: Well @Johnrednex you didn't do a better job explaining. Both of you need to learn how to properly ask questions

Comment: @charlietfl i can show you the full code if you ask for it.

Comment: @Johnrednex you could show a bit more code, and make the question more understandable, for example, getting an idea of what the code actually does might help to better understand or even find a different solution than the one you initially thought was the right way.

Comment: Thank you @Roko C. Buljan to tell me how to answer my question properly instead of blaming me. I like. :)

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan i added my html and js files in my question, and an explanation of what i want to do.

Comment: @Johnrednex it's not clear again. I've seen already similar questions here on SO (after seeing your code `pic = "images/♠" + i + ".jpg";`) and seems like you did not followed people suggestions at all.

Comment: @Johnrednex so what I've understant after some time of exploring (and I'm still not sure I've got it right) is: You want to make a card draggable and droppable, but as soon one drops the card >> you want to prevent that same card to be draggable again. Right?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan you may have already seen a part of the code as i have encoutered other issues that were kindly solved.    In fact this is a poker game that works in one hand with drag and drop (it works nicely) and in the other hand with 4 button. The issue is that when i click on the "Joueur" button, i add an image in the backgound of the slot (where you drop your card). But you can still drag and drop an other card into it. That's wy i want to disable this when you click on the button ;-).

Comment: @Johnrednex ahh, so your game is both playable with buttons and drag-drops. Using a button you want to disable that card being dragged around (cause already played with the button).

Comment: Exactly ! You understood. :-)

Comment: @Johnrednex ahh. no wait So your main issue is: Player can play the card using drag+drop but ALSO using a button. If the player uses a button you want to prevent other cards being dragged to the board (wait for turn)

Comment: Yes that's how i want it to work.

Comment: @Johnrednex  LOL if that's your issue, you've could explain it that way. Three lines of text and you would not get 7 downvotes. And the best answer you would get is to use a variable (instead of messing with draggable things) like `var canPlay = true;` After you click a button you simply set `canPlay` to false. As long as *canPlay* is false, the player cannot drag/btn-click any other card.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your wisdom. May the force be with you @Roko C. Buljan ☺

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off passing a configuration object to the `CartesTurn` function, which would contain the options passed to droppable:

```
var options = {
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: handleCardDrop
}
```

in this case, you can set the drop to `undefined`. And the `CartesTurn` would look like this:

```
CartesTurn(options);
```

and the `appendTo` part like this:

```
$('<div> </div>').appendTo( '#cardSlotsJoueur' ).droppable(options);
```

Comment: I understand what you did, thank you @meskobalazs.